Is there any way to filter based on two tables
I have a query that gets data based on multiple tables
X(id, state) has all employees with state enabled/disabled
Y(id, state) has all groups (of employees) with state enabled/disabled
A(id) scientists/scientist groups with access
B(id, type) has employee ids and groups ids. Each with type employee/group.
so A.a will be either in X or in Y
select A.id, B.type 
from A
inner join B on A.id = B.id

I don't need any columns from X or Y. I need to remove from select those which have X.state="disabled"

Yes, it's not difficult to do. Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

What if A.a is not present at all in X nor Y?

Can A.a be present multiple times in X and/or Y?

Does id represent the same information in all tables?  You state that X contains employees and Y contains groups. Those would typically have distinct sets of ID values. Have you oversimplified the problem statement?

Looks like you just need two NOT EXISTS.
select
  a.id,
  b.type 
from A a
inner join B b on a.id = b.id
  and not exists (select 1
    from x
    where x.id = a.id
      and x.state = 'disabled'
) and not exists (select 1
    from y
    where y.id = a.id
      and y.state = 'disabled'
);


A couple of not exists tests in the where clause should do the trick:
select A.id, B.type 
from A
inner join B
    on A.id = B.id
where not exists (select * from X where X.id = A.id and X.state = 'disabled')
and not exists (select * from Y where Y.id = A.id and Y.state = 'disabled')

Alternately, you can use NOT IN (...) with a subquery that selects ids to be excluded.  This might have better performance, as SQL server might only need to scan the X and Y tables once.
select A.id, B.type 
from A
inner join B
    on A.id = B.id
where A.id not in (
    select X.id
    from X
    where X.state = 'disabled'
    union
    select Y.id
    from Y
    where Y.state = 'disabled'
)


...and UNION ALL is usually faster than UNION

The intent was an implicit distinct, with the hope that SQL Server would map the IDs to an ordered list or hash table for lookups, but yes union all may have the same effect.
